# Is there a way to recover the data of my last push to a git remote?

Tags: git, push

I am trying to make an alias for ubuntu that opens the Merge request of my working in branch. But i need the informations of my last push, is there any way to recover the informations that appear after you push something to a remote?

Tanks.

Comment: I forgot to say that i wanna to recover this information not after i do the git push command. But any time even after i close the terminal.

Comment: You can edit your question, no need to comment on your own question to add to it :) Also, what data are you looking for?

Comment: I don't understand what you need.

Answer (score -1):

1.Go to your git web page

2.Click pull request

3.Click closed

4.Do revert for the specific push then pull origin